# serial monitoring method to test communication via com ports without a serial communication device

Tags: matlab, fpga, uart, serial-communication, spartan

I have a Verilog code simulated and synthesized on ISE design toolkit. I've got an FPGA spartan 6 device which is to be used for the implementation. But there is a problem with the device (probably a power issue) which makes the device unavailable in any of the COM ports when I connected it to my PC. So I want to check whether my Matlab code which I made for serial communication through the device does the desired job. So I need a method to test serial communication via any of the COM ports without connecting a serial com device to the PC. Is there any such method that I can Tx Rx serial data from Matlab to COM ports? Any software or any other method would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to test Matlab serial communication using virtual serial ports.

Download "Freeware Virtual COM Ports Emulator" from: http://freevirtualserialports.com/
I installed it in Windows 10, and it's working (as trial).

Add a pair of two serial ports:
[image]

Execute the following Matlab code sample to verify it's working:

```
s3 = serial('COM3','BaudRate',115200);
s4 = serial('COM4','BaudRate',115200);

fopen(s3);
fopen(s4);

fwrite(s3, uint8([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
%fprintf(s3, '12345');
pause(0.1);

RxBuf = fread(s4, 5)

fclose(s3);
delete(s3);
clear s3

fclose(s4);
delete(s4);
clear s4
```

The output is:

```
RxBuf =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

---

**Bypassing the problem "it only stays for a single test session".**
There is a problem when creating a pair of virtual ports using the software, it only stays for a single test session.
I guess it's a problem with the COM port emulation software.
The following solution, is not a good practice (and not a true solution).

- Declare the serial object as `global`, keeping the object persistent.
- Create the serial object only if it's not created.
- Don't delete and don't clear the serial object.

See the following code sample:

```
global s3 s4

if isempty(s3)
    s3 = serial('COM3','BaudRate',115200);
end

if isempty(s4)
    s4 = serial('COM4','BaudRate',115200);
end

fopen(s3);
fopen(s4);

fwrite(s3, uint8([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
pause(0.1);

RxBuf = fread(s4, 5)

fclose(s3);
%delete(s3);
%clear s3

fclose(s4);
%delete(s4);
%clear s4
```

*You can also look for a better virtual COM port software.*

Comment: I was also going to suggest using virtual COM port, and good job for giving a working example. To simulate better MATLAB talking with _another_ device, you could also use a simple terminal for the other side of your example.

Comment: Thank you @Rotem. It works well. But the problem is when I create a pair of virtual ports using the software, it only stays for a single test session. After that even if the com port is available in device manager, Matlab gives and error saying "COM port is not available". Can it be figured out?

Comment: I have the same problem too. I guess it's a problem with the COM port emulation software.

Answer (score 0):

As Rotem suggested, if you need to communicate via serial line between 2 program of your PC you need a virtual COM port emulator.

It seems you are running on Windows OS so I would recommend a completely free emulator (not a trial one). For Windows I use [com0com Null-modem emulator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/com0com/) (from *SourceForge*).

In the example below I will show how to communicate with "another" device so Matlab will not handle both side of the communication. The other device will be simulated by a simple terminal. For windows I use [RealTerm: Serial/TCP Terminal](https://sourceforge.net/projects/realterm/) (also from *SourceForge*).

---

### Setup:

Execute the setup of both program with all default options. by default *com0com* will create a virtual pair `COM3/COM4` but if these port already exist on your system the program may assign other numbers. Check the numbers before you run the example. (it will also create a `CNCA0/CNCB0` pair but you can ignore this one for now).

[image]

For *RealTerm*, once installed (*don't forget to activate the server registration at the end of the setup, it should be ticked by default though*), it will look like below. Keep all default options, just set the port number and the baud rate if they need to be changed.

[image]

---

### Test MATLAB -> Terminal

You are ready to send Ascii characters or binary values from MATLAB to your device. The animation below shows you an example of both option:
*<sub>you can click on the picture to see it full size. It is running in loop so you may want to wait until it restart from the beginning.</sub>*

### [image]

### Test Terminal -> MATLAB

Below animation shows you how to test the communication in the other way:
[image]

Don't forget to tick `[CR]` `[LF]` on *RealTerm* when you send Ascii characters and want to use the `'%s'` format specifier on MATLAB, as it needs these characters to detect the end of the string.

---

### Note:

- If you have another terminal program that you are more used too, it
  will work the same.
- If the *RealTerm* option does not suit you, or if you want to handle
  both sides of communication from Matlab, then you can use the code
  provided by Rotem in his first answer. Just install *com0com* but
  ignore all the *RealTerm* part.

Comment: I was trying com0com, and installation was faild. I didn't have the patience to check why...

Comment: @Rotem, Windows will likely prompt you with a scary, red highlighted, message "_This driver is not signed, ... bla bla bla_". You have to accept installation of the unsigned driver (i.e. click "_Yes, install anyway_"). I've used the different versions of com0com, for work and personal projects, since more than 10 years and it's quite robust.

Comment: There is installation note I didn't try: *NOTE (x64-based Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008/Windows 7/8): The com0com.sys is a test-signed kernel-mode driver that will not load by default. To enable test signing, enter command:*  `bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON`