# Simulate serial-port communication

Tags: matlab, serial-port

This semester I have a project where I need to send data from my microcontroller to my PC and read/interpret its data. We are doing this using an ftdi cable and using matlab to read the data.
I would like to know if there is a way that I can see if my matlab code works that doesn't involve me going to the lab to test it. That is, if there is a way to simulate receiving data in a USB port of my computer so that I can test if my code is working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to answer a similar question: [serial monitoring method to test communication via com ports without a serial communication device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663949/serial-monitoring-method-to-test-communication-via-com-ports-without-a-serial-co/38667519#38667519). I think the connection is a serial communication over USB (from software point of view you see a serial port, without knowing the physical layer is USB). Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: The simpler approach would be to emulate the microcontroller which sends the data.  Use two USB-to-serial adapters connected to each other.  Use the PC to generate & send the fake data.  Absolutely no modification to your Matlab setup, so it's a better test environment than what you propose.

Comment: Wow that is a brilliant idea ! That will definitely do. Thank you so much !